# ASP.Net MVC can't find a namespace that is not included in the controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

When I try to run this controller action, I get the error:

```
Compiler Error Message: CS0234: The type or namespace name 'ViewModels' does not exist in the namespace 'App.Models' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Line 28:     using App.Web.Mvc;
Line 29:     using App.Models;
Line 30:     using App.Models.ViewModels;
```

The problem is there is no reference to `App.Models.ViewModels` in controller in the first place so I don't know why there is an error, *the 30th line simple does not exists anywhere in my project!*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out that Razor will add a reference to namespaces specified in Web.Config file in your views folder to the top of the complied files for your views. so just removed the reference in webconfig

Views/Web.config:

```
<system.web.webPages.razor>
  <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
    <namespaces>
      <add namespace="App.Models.ViewModels" />
    </namespaces>
  </pages>
</system.web.webPages.razor>
```